# Curve fitting - monotonically increasing derivative

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to get a physical significant fit to some experimental data. I know that not only will the y values increase monotonically with x but also that dy/dx will also increase monotonically. I have tried a number of fitting functions including a polynomial fit and a univariate spline but neither of these has allowed me to produce the fit I am looking for.

So, I'm looking for a curve fitting function (in scipy?) that will allow me to define the known constraints of the final curve. Below is an example of my data, with a fitted line that does not display a monotonically increasing derivative.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =  np.array([[  6.30991828, -10.22329935],
                  [  6.30991828, -10.2127338 ],
                  [  6.47697236, -10.01359361],
                  [  6.47697236,  -9.89353722],
                  [  6.47697236,  -9.81708052],
                  [  6.55108034,  -9.42113403],
                  [  6.55108034,  -9.21932801],
                  [  6.58617165,  -8.40428977],
                  [  6.62007321,  -7.6500927 ]])

interp = np.linspace(min(data[:,0]), max(data[:,0]), 20)
f = np.polyfit(data[:,0], data[:,-1], 3)
data_interp = np.polyval(f, interp)
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'x', interp, data_interp, '-')
```

EDIT: I believe that you can do this in MATLAB with the slmengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Another attempt. I posted half-baked answer before. And I failed in reading too. I hope this is better.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[  6.30991828, -10.22329935],
                  [  6.30991828, -10.2127338 ],
                  [  6.47697236, -10.01359361],
                  [  6.47697236,  -9.89353722],
                  [  6.47697236,  -9.81708052],
                  [  6.55108034,  -9.42113403],
                  [  6.55108034,  -9.21932801],
                  [  6.58617165,  -8.40428977],
                  [  6.62007321,  -7.6500927 ]])

x = data[:, 0]

def polynomial(p, x):
    return p[0]+p[1]*x+p[2]*x**2+p[3]*x**3

def constraint_2nd_der(p):
    return 2*p[2]+6*p[3]*x

def constraint_1st_der(p):
    return p[1]+2*p[2]*x+3*p[3]*x**2

def objective(p):
    return ((polynomial(p, x)-data[:, 1])**2).sum()


cons = (dict(type='ineq', fun=constraint_1st_der), dict(type='ineq', fun=constraint_2nd_der))
res = minimize(objective, x0=np.array([0., 0., 0., 0.]), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
if res.success:
    pars = res.x
    x = np.linspace(data[:, 0].min(), data[:, 0].max(), 100)
    pol = polynomial(pars, x)
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], 'x', x, pol, '-')
    plt.show()
else:
    print 'Failed'
```

Comment: That makes sense but it doesn't seem to be working! If I plot the curve with a finer time step you can see that it is still the same unconstrained cubic polynomial. Has the constraint (cons) been properly applied?

Comment: That looks like an unfinished answer, cons is never used and as far as I understand curve_fit does not accept constraints. Have a look at scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.

Comment: Brilliant, does exactly what I was looking for. Nice methodology too. It doesn't produce a visually brilliant fit but I can constrain by any order derivative, which is great.

Comment: Glad it helped and sorry for previous version. But I recommend that you always check the fit visually - solvers are not always right.

Answer (score 1):

Your data's interesting: you have three discontinuities: at 6.30991828, 6.47697236 and 6.55108034.    Are those real?  Is that what you're trying to capture?

No continuous function can capture those discontinuities correctly.  Your only hope is piecewise fitting on either side of the discontinuities.  You'll have three fits:

1. x <  6.47697236
2. 6.47697236 < x < 6.55108034
3. x > 6.55108034

The function is multi-valued at the discontinuities, of course.

If those aren't meaningful to you, I'd say that any cubic polynomial would give you a continuous, increasing first derivative.

[image]

Comment: The discontinuities aren't real, there are just multiple tests carried out at those values. Would I be better off taking an average of the repeats and then fitting the curve through the averaged values?

Comment: As you can see, a least squares fit will minimize the mean square error and calculate the coefficients from the raw data.  I'd do that.  You can see that the R value is high, and the visual on the fit is good for this third-order curve.  Good enough?

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to choose a family of functions and analytically compute your derivative. This will give you a constraint that you input into your optimization routine.

Comment: The problem is that the derivative of the polynomial curve does not monotonically increase. I need to use the derivative of the curve for subsequent analysis and the reduction in dx/dy is not physically sensical.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now.  Perhaps adding a Lagrange multiplier to enforce that would manage it.  I don't know how to do it in a typical least squares package.  Maybe this can help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/polynomial-fitting-where-polynomial-must-be-monotonically-increasing

Comment: I missed one repeated point at 6.310.  If these truly are multiple tests, perhaps you'd be better off fitting each one individually and then treating the coefficients as another population.  You'll still have this constraint issue.  Interesting....

Comment: Here's a paper that shows how to do least squares with Lagrange multipliers: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0405/GEORGOPOLOUS/Constrained_least_squares.pdf

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for that. I might just switch to MATLAB as I think John D'Errico has produced tool which allows you to add in these type of constraints - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24443-slm-shape-language-modeling .

Comment: That might be a good idea.  Thank you for an interesting question and discussion.  Good luck.

Comment: If you insist on a polynomial fitting keep in mind the problems associated with it (over-fitting, instability). But you can still impose a condition on positive second derivative.

Comment: @Martin I'm not a big fan of using polynomial fitting but it is sometimes a useful tool! How can I enforce a positive second derivative?

Comment: I will produce an answer if I have some free time but until that see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)

Comment: @Martin I'll have a look through those now. Cheers.